# Limits in probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ has a probability density function like this:

$f_x(x)=0$ when $x \le 0$, $f_x(x)=e^{-x}$ when $x>0$.

Find the density function of $Y=(X-1)^2$.

So I do the following: $F_y(y)=P(Y<y)=P((X-1)^2<y)=P(X\in (1-\sqrt{y}, 1+\sqrt{y}))$ 
Now I understand that I am first supposed to find the cumulative distribution function, and than, by derivating the CDF I am supposed to get the needed PDF.

What I don't understand is how do I know the limits of my integrals when calculating the CDF. I know I am supposed to figure those out based on the given PDF for X, but I am just not sure how.

Comment: The PDF is defined on the whole real line (simply, it's zero when $x\leq0$. You *can* thus integrate on $\Bbb R$ and reduce the interval to $[0,+\infty[$ since the integral on $]-\infty,0]$ is zero. However, bear in mind that the CDF is defined as $$P(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(u)\mathrm du$$.

Comment: okay, I understand that. But how do I know where $y$ stands based on what I know about $x$?

Comment: What do you mean? You have correctly found the interval $(1-\sqrt{y},1+\sqrt{y})$, thus you could find the CDF of $Y$, if you find first the CDF of $X$ (which is easy, given you know its PDF: it's $P(X\leq x)=1-e^{-x}$ for $x\geq0$, and $0$ for $x<0$).